# Can we write formal (mechanical) proof of any theorem?

Tags: formal-proofs

why formal proofs are not widely used? sometimes non formal proofs are cumbersome.
are there any "important" theorems that have been proved formally

Comment: Relevant: [State of the progress of automated proof checking](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113316/state-of-the-progess-of-the-automated-proof-checking)

Answer (score 0):

Because are very difficult to write:

To write a correct and complete formal proof one must have a complete command of both maths and logic.

Then a lot of work on all fields of mathematics .

Anyway the only book as far as i know existing which is full of formal proofs is one titled:

FORMAL PROOFS IN MATHS In amazon.com